# ¿La palabra "también" va entre comas?

Tags: gramática, redacción

Tengo esta frase:

> Tal estudio, también, señala las propiedades que deben presentar...

¿Es correcta así?, o ¿no lleva comas? Incluso, ¿podría llevar sólo la primera coma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ¿podría llevar sólo la primera coma?

Quiero hacer mención especial a esta pregunta porque es un error que, a mi modo de ver, es bastante común:

> Tal estudio, también señala las propiedades que deben presentar...

En esta frase el sujeto [Tal estudio] está separado verbo [señala] a través de una coma. Esto es un error, como se explica [acá](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=V1EqcYbX4D61AWBBrd):

> 3.1. Es incorrecto escribir coma entre el sujeto y el verbo de una oración, incluso cuando el sujeto está compuesto de varios elementos separados por comas...

Otros ejemplos de uso correcto e incorrecto de la coma en [fundeu](http://www.fundeu.es/escribireninternet/la-coma-criminal/).

Comment: Excelente el enlace de fundeu. Hay unos ejemplos muy buenos de _la coma criminal_  :-)

Comment: Gracias, excelente aporte sobre la coma criminal

Answer (score 7):

A mí escrito así con comas me suena raro. Mucho mejor sin ellas:

> Tal estudio también señala las propiedades...
>   Tal estudio señala también las propiedades...

Ten en cuenta que el adverbio *también* no forma un grupo sintáctico por sí solo, sino que siempre necesita acompañar a otra parte de la oración, incluso en el caso de que aparezca solo:

> -¿Juan también viene?
>   -También [viene].

Por tanto, no se debe escribir entre comas. Puedes ver multitud de ejemplos en la *Nueva gramática de la lengua española*. Sigue [este enlace](http://aplica.rae.es/gramatica/) y en el cuadro de búsqueda a la izquierda introduce "también", y en las opciones a la derecha marca la opción "Curs." para restringir la búsqueda a casos de ejemplo. Verás frases como las siguientes:

> *Léase también que podemos mutar como el camaleón, según desde dónde soplen los vientos...
>
>   También tuvo unas pocas de sofocaciones a cuenta de eso.
>
>   Y también hacían lo que llamaban vida social, especialmente en la avenida Recoleta...
>
>   Doña Matilde también tenía su buena noticia que contar.
>
>   Pasada la primera temporada de euforia, también tu tío empezó a tener días malos.*

Nótese que este último ejemplo bien se podría haber redactado como "tu tío también empezó a tener días malos", solo que en este caso se desplaza "también" al principio de la frase para recalcar que acompaña a "tu tío" más que a "empezó a tener días malos". Es decir, la coma solo está separando dos frases y no tiene nada que ver con "también".

Answer (score 1):

Para mí, el significado varía según lleve comas o no, porque las comas te fuerzan a hacer una pausa que recalca la importancia del sujeto (tal estudio).

- **Sin comas**, para mí querría decir que ya has listado cosas que el estudio señala. Y ahora quieres añadir que señala "las propiedades que deben presentar" además de las cosas que has mencionado antes.
- **Con comas**, sin embargo, el significado sería a la inversa: ya había otros estudios que señalaban "las propiedades que deben presentar", y este estudio, además de aquellos otros, vuelve a señalar eso mismo. Equivalentemente, se podría decir "También tal estudio señala las propiedades que...".

Pero definitivamente, como dice Mauricio, con una única coma no se debe escribir.

Comment: ¡Exactamente! Tu apreciación me parece muy acertada, y también creo que las comas cambian el sentido.